# Is "once saved, always saved" strictly a Calvinist view?

Tags: reformed-theology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the doctrines of “Perseverance of the Saints” and “Eternal Security?”](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/what-is-the-difference-between-the-doctrines-of-perseverance-of-the-saints-and)

I know that Calvinists believe in "Eternal Security", or "Perseverance of the Saints" as it's called in the TULIP acronym.  But are there other Christian groups that also believe in the concept of "once saved, always saved", without accepting the other four points of Calvinist theology?

<sub>*And if I'm inappropriately equating "Eternal Security", "Perseverance of the Saints" and "Once saved, always saved" terms, please correct me on this.*</sub>

Comment: "Perseverence of the saints" is typically used by Reformed ("calvinist") types, whereas "eternal security" and "once saved, always saves" are used by others. The concepts are related but the groups typically eschew the other's understanding of salvific security

Comment: I can't speak to other viewpoints beyond Arminianism, but the equating of the three terms is valid :) .. (sidebar, I always learned it as "perseverance/preservation of the saints" for the 'P' in TULIP)

Comment: @Ray: Do you think it would be better, then, if I ask about the differences between the various concepts?

Comment: That might be a good follow-up. There is a real question here, though, as well, and "yes" would probably be an unsatisfying answer, so it might make sense to just broaden your question

Comment: I've asked my follow-up question... I wonder if that makes this one a dupe, though... [What is the difference between the doctrines of "Perseverance of the Saints" and "Eternal Security?"](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3106)

Comment: After talking with Flimzy I decided it would be best to get some answers to the definition of these scrambled terms, then later edit this question might be more answerable with a specific definition in mind and we can re-opened it as an independent question.

Comment: @Caleb (and Flimzy)  I don't think this a duplicate of the linked question (either it doesn't definitely answer this question, or possibly it answers it tangentially, but in my view incorrectly - I think the answer to this question is definitely no, but the answer at the duplicate seems to imply it is yes), perhaps this can be edited to remove the reference to eternal security and reopened?